# How to open a .txt file automatically at the end of a C program?

Tags: c, file, fopen

```
int main(void)
{    
    char name[] = "t2.txt";  
    FILE *datei;  
    datei = fopen(name, "a+");

    fprintf(datei, "Hello");
    fclose(datei);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This program writes the word "hello" in the t2.txt file. 
to see this I should always open the file by myself. But I want to make the program which open it automatically at the end.. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm surprised this program does anything...

Comment: You answered your own question (that is, the one in the title), but I don't understand the one after your code.

Comment: Why the close votes? There were obviously some typos...

Comment: @wormsparty I think he automatically wants to open it in an editor to see the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your platform. For windows, you could use the system method:

```
int system ( const char * command );
```

with

```
system("notepad t2.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(void)
{    
    char name[] = "t2.txt";  
    FILE *datei;  
    datei = fopen(name, "a+");

    fprintf(datei, "Hello");
    fclose(datei);

    system("cat t2.txt");//this will shows you content of file on your terminal
    return 0;
}
```

if you are working with linux then this is the **GOOD** way to do so ...i always do this

Comment: Why is this the best way to do it? (leaving aside the fact that you didn't answer the question - he said he wants to open the file, not print its contents to the console). "This is the best way to do it" is a pretty strong affirmation, you should have something to back it up.

Comment: i thought by his question that after doing some file operation he wants to make sure whether that are done or not. so instead of opening file every time why dont just print the content of file on terminal and verify ..!!!  in this way this is the best way...

Comment: You just argued why you answered a different question... and I agree with you on this, this is what he **might** want. Regardless, you still haven't argued why this is **the best** way.

Comment: I wasn't trying to diss your answer. I'm also here to learn. I want to know what **the best way** of doing anything is. But I also need some proof. If this is the best way, please state why and I'm sure everyone will appreciate it, including me.

Comment: i dont know any somuch logical reason but just to open file in other application will take to much time and also resources. and at the end you need to close thet application also..like notepad if file is small then best way to see its content is cat.

Comment: Honestly, I'd avoid ever calling `system()`. It's easy to setup any build system to run a little script after the program run. It helps keep useless stuff out of your program, and isn't any less effective

Comment: @Dave yea thats also better way to doing that..+1

Answer (score 1):

The right thing to do in this situation is to wrap the command in a batch or shell script. That way, your program does what it's specified to do, and you get a nice automated review at the end

blah.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
./program
cat t2.txt
```

Then, to run your program, you'd

```
./blah.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to talk to your operating system and tell it to open the file. This depends on the operating system, but usually you can do this with the `system` call which you'll find in stdlib.h, use the 'open' shell command.